# Android textlistener on edit text crashes program

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I'm trying to simply add something to a listview when the enter key on the edittext is pressed. I also have an onclick listener on a button that will call the same function to add the word to the listview. The button was working fine until I added the textwatcher. Now if the function I am calling is in the listener, the whole app crashes if I press enter, or push the button. If I remove the class from the textwatcher, then the app doesn't crash if I push enter, but it will if I push the button. Any ideas? I haven't done android in forever, so I'm completely stuck.

XML

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:hint="Enter a new item"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/myDoneButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/myDoneButton"
    android:layout_above="@+id/myListView"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Item"
    android:id="@+id/myDoneButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="onAddItem"
    />
```

JAVA

```
//On enter listener for mEditText (within oncreate)
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.charAt(s.length() - 1) == '\n') { 
                onAddItem(mListView);
                Log.d("TEST RESPONSE", "Enter was pressed");
            }
        }
    });

//Outside of oncreate
public void onAddItem(View v) {
    String itemText = mEditText.getText().toString();
    itemsAdapter.add(itemText);
    mEditText.setText("");
    writeItems();
}
```

Here's the pertinent information from Logcat

```
04-11 16:26:23.619 13377-13377/com.ivieinc.groceryapp E/AndroidRuntime:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.ivieinc.groceryapp, PID: 13377                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick 
... (removed for clarity)                                                                 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
... (removed for clarity)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: -1 < 0                                                                       
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.charAt(SpannableStringBuilder.java:117)
at com.ivieinc.groceryapp.MainActivity$1.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:69)
at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:8007)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4351)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4199)
at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:84)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4174)
at com.ivieinc.groceryapp.MainActivity.onAddItem(MainActivity.java:108)
... (removed for clarity)
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Post your logcat please.

Comment: I am a little confused. Are you saying onAddItem works fine until you add the TextWatcher, and then when you have the TextWatcher and hit enter or press the button the app crashes?

Comment: @zgc7009, yes that is what I am saying. Before I added the TextWatcher I just had the button on click and it worked fine. Of course, nothing happened when you hit enter in the edittext, it would just proceed to a new line.

Comment: It is because `onAddItem()` has the code `mEditText.setText("");` which changes the text to "" and triggers the `afterTextChanged()` method which will crash at `s.charAt(s.length()-1)` since that is charAt(-1). Just make it `if(s.length() > 0 && s.charAt(s.length()-1))`

Comment: Why are you passing a view as parameter if you are not using it? ???

Comment: As a side note, this isn't how you should handle checking for enter being pressed. You need to look at imeOptions="done" or any of the other variations of the attribute you may need.

Comment: @zgc7009 have you tried imeOptions on a nexus 5 (android 5.0) successfully? I read somewhere that it does not work on a few phone, and I got no response in my emulator.

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa no idea, haha. I was just following an example.

Comment: @zgc7009 I tried your suggestion, but I got this error in the gradle build. "Error: bad operand types for binary operator '&&' first type: boolean second type:char"

Comment: It wasn't the full code sorry, it should be `if(s.length() > 0 && s.charAt(s.length() - 1) == '\n')` and no I haven't heard of imeOption="actionDone" not working before. Not that it isn't true that it doesn't, the joy of working with Android is trying to make it work for the 10000 devices out there. Anyway, the check to make sure it is of length larger than 0 will make sure you don't check the value of a character in a negative position in a string.

Comment: Yeah, not sure if it's true or not (I couldn't get it to work, but that's not saying much), but that's just what I saw on a question here. Your code works though, thanks! And now I understand the issue, I feel more confident in android, so kudos to you! Make it an answer and I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
if (s.charAt(s.length() - 1) == '\n') {
```

Since s is empty, `s.length` is zero and you are trying to get the char at index -1...

You have to validate the **Editable s**